# Strange behaviour of wicket TextField

Tags: java, string, wicket, textfield, tostring

I am developing a wicket client for my webservice.

On my first steps with wicket I noticed a strange behaviour. I have a form where I enter an username:

```
         <form wicket:id="registerForm">
            User Name <input type="text" wicket:id="userId"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
         </form>
```

My Submit for this looks like:

```
private TextField userIdField;
private Form form;


public Register() {

    userIdField = new TextField("userId", new Model(""));

    form = new RegisterForm("registerForm");
    form.add(userIdField);
    add(form);
  }


class RegisterForm extends Form {
  public RegisterForm(String id) {
    super(id);
  }
  @Override
  public void onSubmit() {

    String userId = Register.this.getUserId();


   if(userId == "test") {
       System.out.println("normal");
   }
   else {
       System.out.println("strange");
   }

  }
}



protected String getUserId() {
    return userIdField.getDefaultModelObjectAsString();

}

}
```

When I enter test in my form the console says "strange".

Whats wrong with it?

Comment: You have to check Strings with the `equals`-method if you want to check the equality of the content. See also [here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that checks for equality in Java regarding Strings should use the [`String.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method. Using `==` will only return `true` when both operands are the same instance.

```
if (userId.equals("test")) {
    System.out.println("normal");
}
```

This question might be useful to you: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/851811)

Comment: Stupid beginners mistake. Thanks a lot!